# Difference between $('selector')[0] ,$('selector').eq(index) in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between `$('#div1 a')[0]` and `$('#div1 a').eq(0)` for the following markup

```
<div id="div1">
<a href="#">click</a>
</div>.
```

Please Help.

Comment: In your markup, all three will return the same. (no difference)

Comment: Using the square brackets is a shorthand for using .get http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: @meo I get you... looking at your hide example... thanks for correcting

Comment: This question took a while to find until I changed my search string from "jquery, .eq[0] vs [0]" to "jquery, difference between .eq[0] and  [0]"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('div1 a')[0]
```

returns a direct reference to a DOM element

```
$('div1 a').eq(0)
```

returns a JQuery object

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/DP8as/

This will **not** work:

```
$('div a')[0].hide()
```

this will;

```
$('div a').eq(0).hide()
```