# Can't access Jquery object inner data

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I have a plugin in WordPress that shows individual rating in comments area. I am trying to get votes for each individual user in a div with data field. Here is the structure.

```
<div id="r1" class="widget_rate"
      data-post-id="<?php echo $post_id ?>"
      data-user-id="<?php echo $user_id;  ?>"
      data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>"
      data-total="***<?php echo $data;*** ?>"
     >

     <div data-rating="1" class="star_1 stars_ratings"><b>1</b></div>
     <div data-rating="2" class="star_2 stars_ratings"><b>2</b></div>
     <div data-rating="3" class="star_3 stars_ratings"><b>3</b></div>
     <div data-rating="4" class="star_4 stars_ratings"><b>4</b></div>
     <div data-rating="5" class="star_5 stars_ratings"><b>5</b></div>

 </div>
```

data-total is what I am after. But when I load page jQuery set rating for all users according to first value. I thought that might jQuery only called once but when i checked in a browser I found all instances of "widget_rate" div. Here is,

```
   [div#r1.widget_rate, div#r1.widget_rate, div#r1.widget_rate, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".widget_rate", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function…]
0: div#r1.widget_rate
1: div#r1.widget_rate
2: div#r1.widget_rate
context: document
length: 3
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
selector: ".widget_rate"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

I have three comments and I have all three instances so I tried to access them by assigning

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate")[0];
```

And I can see the value in outerHTML but I can't access it. It returns undefined function error.

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate")[0].html();
var temp = $(".widget_rate")[0].outerHTML;
```

But nothing is working. I would be grateful to have a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access with [0] you get only element. Not Jquery object. You must reuse $ function.

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate")[0].html();
```

İf you only want first of three you can use **:first** selector

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate:first").html();
```

There are lots of selector at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: It returns four child divs but what I need is occurences of widget_rate and that happens three times.

Answer (score 0):

Use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for that

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate").eq(0).html();
```

Or simple

```
var temp = $(".widget_rate").html(); //It will give for first one.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/14/)

Comment: I have mentioned above I can get the first element but When I try to access its data or anything I receive an "Uncaught type Error: Undefined is not a function."

Comment: Its not working What is the difference between Its same thing either you use eq or directly use [0].

Comment: No they are not same, see here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001101/difference-between-selector0-selector-eqindex-in-jquery,

Comment: @Epistemologist you can't call jquery functions on `[0]` objects.

Comment: Thanks It worked but I used this                                      var temp = $(".widget_rate:eq(0)").data().total;

Comment: By the way your last answer was correct. If I use eq outside I don't get intended result.